# Download pdf does not loaded on new window from ios13

Tags: reactjs, ios13, react-pdf

I am using react pdf plugin for a web application to handle pdf. However, in iOS 13, user clicks on the download succesfully downloaded the pdf to the mobile, but it is not opened in the new window as what usually the case where the pdf automatically opened once download completed. Also, users cannot go back or open on a multi-window to close.

Please note that this is only happening in Ios 13 above and not on android, Windows or iOS 12 and bellow

Any suggestions or any recommendations to fix.

Comment: Can you provide the source code so everyone could test that out?

Comment: <a href={urll} target="_blank" download="statement.pdf"><img src="download.svg" /></a>

Comment: to add more information this happening if the server side return the html content to render as pdf the issue has been occuring but if normal pdf url its working fine. the server side is java